# why keras embedding not learning (for recommendation system)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-embedding, recommendation-engine

I am trying to use keras embedding to do a collaborative filtering style recommendation system. It is the traditional user item score (binary: 0,1) data format:

```
  user_id item_id score
   1       4       0
   1       2       0
   ...
   3000    32      1
```

I used the following model, but the training curve is not change across epoches. I want to know what may be some of the reasons that training loss basically not change but **the accuracy is the same across epoches**.

```
user_input=Input(shape=(1,),name='user_input',dtype='int64')
user_embedding=Embedding(n_users,n_latent_factors,name='user_embedding',\
                         embeddings_initializer='he_normal', 
                  embeddings_regularizer=l2(1e-6))(user_input)   
user_vec=Flatten(name='FlattenUsers')(user_embedding)
user_vec=Dropout(0.30)(user_vec)

item_input=Input(shape=(1,),name='item_input',dtype='int64')
item_embedding=Embedding(n_items,n_latent_factors,name='item_embedding', \
                         embeddings_initializer='he_normal',
                  embeddings_regularizer=l2(1e-6))(item_input)
item_vec=Flatten(name='FlattenItems')(item_embedding)
item_vec=Dropout(0.30)(item_vec)

sim=dot([user_vec,item_vec],name='Simalarity-Dot-Product',axes=1)
nn = Concatenate()([user_vec, item_vec])
nn =Dense(50,activation='relu')(nn)
nn =Dropout(0.4)(nn)
nn =Dense(1,activation='relu')(nn)
nn_model =keras.models.Model([user_input, item_input],nn)
nn_model.summary()

nn_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3, decay = 0.9),loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history_v3 = nn_model.fit([train.user_id,train.item_id],train.score, batch_size= batch_size,
                          epochs =10, validation_data = ([valid.user_id,valid.item_id],valid.score),
                          verbose = 1)

Epoch 1/10
912357/912357 [==============================] - 39s 43us/step - loss: 3.4449 - accuracy: 0.4674 - val_loss: 2.6401 - val_accuracy: 0.4534
Epoch 2/10
912357/912357 [==============================] - 38s 43us/step - loss: 3.3249 - accuracy: 0.4674 - val_loss: 2.5783 - val_accuracy: 0.4534
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that it's a binary classification task, I suggest you use sigmoid as the activation function in the last layer instead of relu. Sigmoid produces output vectors where each element in the interval [0,1] and not mutually exclusive, which we can interpret as probabilities. You can retrieve the prediction in true class in this way:

```
(nn_model.predict([test.user_id,test.item_id]).ravel()>0.5)+0
```

We get class 0 to all the predictions below 0.5 otherwise 1